# Speeding Up Rails App With Large Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, datatables

I built a Rails app that tracks my business' inventory of cellphones. We have 1,426 inventory objects right now.  When I pull up the inventories index page (a table of all inventory created) on our Heroku-hosted app the page takes **over 10 seconds to load.**

I am looking into fragment caching, adding indexes on all applicable association keys, and trying to figure out how to paginate the results.

What are the best ways to speed up my page loads?

Comment: Are you using jquery-rails-datatables? https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails

Comment: Your problem is not that the table is large:  1,426 records is not a large amount.  Your problem is that you are **displaying the data for all the records on your web page**.  You need to only display a subset of records at any one time, eg with pagination, see answer below.

Comment: Thanks all, I am using jquery-rails-datatables.  I should have mentioned that I'm also using their paginate feature, although I'm not sure that limits how many rows are actually rendered on page load.

Answer (score 2):

You could use pagination, with pagination you can limit the the amount of inventory objects per page.

Will paginate is a gem for rails that takes care of this found on: 
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Answer (score 1):

Generic [answer](http://blog.skylight.io/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-your-rails-app/) for generic question!

Comment: Thanks Dusht, this looks like a really helpful resource!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might be happening is that you have N+1 queries, install the bullet gem. That gem basically will tell alert you in development mode about all the N+1 queries you are doing.

In case you don't know what N+1 queries:

Suppose you have this in your controller:

```
def show 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

And suppose that the user has cellphones models related, so in your view you do something like:

```
= @user.cellphones.last.number
```

That will generate a query to find the cellphone, and for each thing you have that do this too. 
So to solve this you can do something like:

```
def show
  @user = User.includes(:cellphone).find(params[:id]) 
end
```

That will basically give both user and cellphones to the view.
This may not solve your problem but at least it will help some.

Comment: Thanks alebian.  I didn't think I had an N+1 because my query is @inventories = Inventory.order('id DESC').  But I just looked at the development log and it does look that way because of some of the data I'm pulling in the view.  Working on it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, everyone, and I apologize for the generic question.

This was most certainly an N+1 problem that got solved by eager loading, using .includes().  I took a look at the development log and noticed the tower of queries.  After using two .includes() for the associated model data that appears in my view's table, the page load time is down to ~1.7 seconds.

Thanks again!
Brennan